# IntelliJ can not debug

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, junit4

i get following error when (locally) trying to debug by junit test in IntelliJ 2018.2.4:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -XXdebug
```

i think there is a configuration error, it should actually be `-Xdebug` instead of `-XXdebug`, but i can not find it anywhere in the settings.

a grep in the `.idea` or `.intellij` folders did not find any such a setting either.

any help greatly appreciated.

many thanks

Michael

Comment: @Carcigenicate: i did find anything special there, creating a new run config does not help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `idea.properties` (which is normally located in the IDEA installation directory), there's a property named `idea.debug.key`, with the value set to `-XXdebug`. Change it to `-Xdebug` and everything should work.